Pandas rolling average in time window
I have the dataframe below. event_timestamp is a column of type dtype: datetime64[ns].
event_timestamp                 value
2024-02-02 09:29:19.623481531   8
2024-02-02 09:29:19.907333355   9
2024-02-02 09:29:19.907373437   10
2024-02-02 09:29:21.366842178   11
2024-02-02 09:29:21.366886264   12
2024-02-02 09:29:21.512928275   13
2024-02-02 09:29:21.512968294   14
2024-02-02 09:29:23.050536162   15
2024-02-02 09:29:23.300983260   16
2024-02-02 09:29:23.318874509   17
2024-02-02 09:29:23.318916726   18

What I am trying to achieve: For each row, calculate the average of 'value' in the next 1s.
Expected output:

1st row: avg(8,9,10) = 9
2nd row: avg(9,10) = 9.5
3rd row: avg(10) = 10
4th row: avg(11,12,13,14) = 12.5
5th row: avg(2,13,14) = 13

I tried with the below but no luck, the output was in the 'avg_value_next_1s' was wrong, though I can't tell what it's doing:
data = {
    'event_timestamp': ['2024-02-02 09:29:19.623481531', '2024-02-02 09:29:19.907333355', '2024-02-02 09:29:19.907373437', '2024-02-02 09:29:21.366842178', '2024-02-02 09:29:21.366886264', '2024-02-02 09:29:21.512928275', '2024-02-02 09:29:21.512968294', '2024-02-02 09:29:23.050536162', '2024-02-02 09:29:23.300983260'],
    'value': [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
}

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to timestamp object
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])

df = df.set_index("event_timestamp") 
df['avg_value_next_1s'] = df['value'].rolling('1s').mean()
    

EDIT: How does the on= parameter work?
I would like to keep the original index, so not set the index as above. When trying the below in order to do the rolling operation, but it throws an error: invalid on specified as event_timestamp, must be a column (of DataFrame), an Index or None
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
# Convert 'event_timestamp' column to timestamp object
df['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_timestamp'])

df['avg_value_next_1s'] = df['value'].rolling('1s', on='event_timestamp').mean()


Since you want the next 1s, you should invert the input before rolling:
df['avg_value_next_1s'] = df.loc[::-1, 'new_column'].rolling('1s').mean()

Output:
                               new_column  avg_value_next_1s
event_timestamp                                             
2024-02-02 09:29:19.623481531           8                9.0
2024-02-02 09:29:19.907333355           9                9.5
2024-02-02 09:29:19.907373437          10               10.0
2024-02-02 09:29:21.366842178          11               12.5
2024-02-02 09:29:21.366886264          12               13.0
2024-02-02 09:29:21.512928275          13               13.5
2024-02-02 09:29:21.512968294          14               14.0
2024-02-02 09:29:23.050536162          15               15.5
2024-02-02 09:29:23.300983260          16               16.0


Wow... Works. So I need to do both directions. I.e. avg price 1s after, and 1s before. Is this best course of action to create two columns, one with the inverted df for the forward looking, and one with the regular df for backward looking?

If you want 1s before/after in the same window use 2s with center=True. It is not an issue to invert the columns since index alignment is performed during assignment.

I've added an edit section - trying to use the on= parameter so that I don't have to set my index to the timestamp and can keep the original index, but it is throwing an error. Am I doing something wrong here?

@IGottaLearnMath I'd recommend to use the timestamp as index, while using a column is possible it doesn't always behave smoothly. In your code the error is due to slicing before the rolling, which removes the timestamp column. You would need to slice after: df.rolling('1s', on='event_timestamp')['value'].mean()

duckdb：
(
 df1.sql.select("*,date_trunc('second',event_timestamp::datetime) event_timestamp2")
 .select("*,avg(value) over(partition by event_timestamp2 rows between current row and unbounded following) col1")
)

